# my docker-compose app doesn't give me error when uploading files with multer but nothing is uploaded

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, multer

I am trying to upload a csv file throw multer it sends back a response with no errors but nothing is uploaded. I am using docker-compose.
and there is a file in the request when i log it

**this is docker-compose file**

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  app: 
    build: .
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
  mongodb:
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - "27018:27018"
    command: mongod --port 27018 --bind_ip_all
```

**and this is my route**

```
let storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, callBack) => {
        callBack(null, './uploads')
    },
    filename: (req, file, callBack) => {
        console.log(req.currentUser);
        callBack(
        null,
        req.currentUser.courseId,
        )
    },
});

var upload = multer({
    storage
});

router.post('/api/upload-csv',requireAuth, upload.single('csv') ,async(req,res) =>{
    console.log(req.file)
    res.send({done: true})
});
```

Comment: How do you know it's not uploading anything? Are you looking in the right place? Remember that the storage path will be inside the docker container, not on the host.

Comment: i checked it with the shell and i havn't found anything uploaded